# Active admin : form on dashboard not related to any models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a rails 3 application which uses the ActiveAdmin gem.

Is there a way to make a form in the dashboard page. A form that is not related to any models ? In my case, a form to select time period to display some stats ?

I have tried :

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs "test" do
    f.input :time, label: "Duration", as: :select, collection: [['24h', 24], ['1 week', '1w'], ['1 month', '1m']]
  end
  f.actions
end
```

But i'm getting an "undefined methods errors" for `f.inputs`. Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create a form partial like this:

```
-# admin/whatever/_form.html.haml
= semantic_form_for 'whatever', :url => admin_whatevers_path do |f|
  = f.inputs :name => 'tests' do %>
    = f.input :time, collection: [['24h', 24], ['1 week', '1w'], ['1 month', '1m']]
```

and tell activeadmin to use the partial like this:

```
#admin/whatever.rb
form :partial => 'form'
```

Comment: You need to use `render :partial => 'form'` and put your templates into `app/views/admin/whatever/_whatever.html.erb` or equivalent